# Using SUBQUERY with multiple attributes

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have 3 entities, "Bar", "Waiter", "Product" the relationship is as follows, A "Bar" has one to many relationship with "Waiter" and the same from Waiter to Product.

I need to know which Bars has been serving Products with certain attributes.

The entity Im fetching is Bars, 
So far I've tried:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(toWaiter, $x, ANY $x.toProduct.dateServed > %@ AND $x.toProduct.dateConsumed > %@).@count > 0), [NSDate date], [NSDate date]];
```

Where I get

> Only allowed one toMany/manyToMany relationship in subquery expression collection

If I try:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(toWaiter, $x, ANY $x.toProduct.dateServed > %@ ANY AND $x.toProduct.dateConsumed > %@).@count > 0), [NSDate date], [NSDate date]];
```

Two ANYs, I get the same error,

> Only allowed one toMany/manyToMany relationship in subquery expression collection

Which is the correct way to subquery for more than one attribute?

thanks.

This is the model: [image]

Comment: Why do you need `toBar` relationship in your predicate? You said that you already have an array of waiters for a particular bar.

Comment: Sorry, I dont, I want to query Bars that have been served Products with those qualities, I will edit

Comment: Is there any chance that you can post an example project somewhere? Unfortunately setting up the entire project with Core Data model and stuff to test just that is a pain.

Comment: Im afraid not. I think is more of a theorical question, no need of debugging my code. How would you subquery 2 attributes of a Model like the above.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by nesting two SUBQUERY clauses together:

```
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(toWaiter, $x, SUBQUERY($x.toProduct, $y, $y.dateServed > %@ AND $y.dateConsumed > %@).@count > 0).@count > 0", [NSDate date], [NSDate date]];
```

Or, in (vaguely) natural language: "fetch all the `Bars` with a non-zero count of (`Waiters` with a non-zero count of (`Products` with both `dateServed` and `dateConsumed` greater than today))".

Comment: Great! thanks. Im wondering how would be the syntax to also filter by a certain values of Waiter. Waiters that have worked between 2 times, and have also served that product.

Comment: How do you model the times that a waiter works?  Is that another to-many relationship?

Comment: No, those are attributes in the Waiter Object. Waiter.startWork and Waiter.endWork.

Comment: That's a reasonably complex query on its own, so I would test it on its own, and then combine it with the above query.  Assuming the period you are interested in is `startTime` to `endTime`, and you want `Waiters` who (`startWork` before `endTime`) and (`endWork` after `startTime`), then your predicate should look something like this: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(toWaiter, $x, `$x.startWork < %@ AND $x.endWork > %@ AND` SUBQUERY($x.toProduct, $y, $y.dateServed > %@ AND $y.dateConsumed > %@).@count > 0).@count > 0", `endTime, startTime,` [NSDate date], [NSDate date]];

Comment: Haha, great I got to the same conclusion, yes that is right!